# How to get the index of the current char while iterating over a string in scala

Tags: string, scala, loops, foreach

I am very new to scala and am trying to print the char at each index in a string as follows —

```
val p = "each other we love"
p.foreach((x, i) => println(s"CHAR@$i $x"))
```

I assumed that the second argument would be the index of the character which obviously isn't true and thus getting a type error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use zipWithIndex, index is not supplied to you during normal traversal:

```
p.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (x, i) => println(s"CHAR@$i $x") }
```